# How to fix the incorrectly extends interface 'Request<ParamsDictionary>' error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express

I have the following code that is failing but I'm not able to understand why this is failing.  Any suggestions?

**code example**

```
import * as express from "express";

export const router = express.Router();

export interface RARequest<B = {}, P = {}, Q = {}> extends express.Request {
  headers: {
    "device-id": string;
    "x-forwarded-for": string;
    authorization: string;
  };
  params: P;
  query: Q;
  body: B;
}

export interface RAResponse<T = {}> extends express.Response {
  json(data: T): express.Response;
  locals: {
    operatorUrn: string;
  };
}
```

**Error message**

```
error TS2430: 
Interface 'RARequest<B, P, Q>' incorrectly extends interface 'Request<ParamsDictionary>'. 
Types of property 'params' are incompatible. 
Type 'P' is not assignable to type 'ParamsDictionary'. 
30 export interface RARequest<B = {}, P = {}, Q = {}> extends express.Request
```

**Update after advice**

```
export interface RARequest<B = {}, P = {}, Q = {}> extends express.Request {
  headers: {
    "device-id": string;
    "x-forwarded-for": string;
    authorization: string;
  };
  params: ParamsDictionary;
  query: Q;
  body: B;
}
```

This update produces this error message

**error message**

```
Property 'params' of exported interface has or is using private name
'ParamsDictionary'.ts(4033)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `params: P` to `params: ParamsDictionary`.

Comment: it's not my code, I have no idea B, P and Q refer to, any ideas?

Comment: have tried, see my update - the change produces an error